# Auto Login in MVC5 using owin authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I have recently been playing around with ASP.NET MVC5 and the new OWIN authentication middleware. I want my users to register . After a user logs in successfully, I just need the auto login automatically using the ad account so that by stop asking user credentials again

Comment: Code? We need more details...

Comment: problem is i am new to mvc5 so having no idea how to start ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want the user to remain logged in, force the IsPersistent flag to true when logging them in:

Out of the box code (from AccountController.cs):

```
// POST: /Account/Login
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
      if (user != null)
      {
         await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
         return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
      }
      else
      {
         ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
      }
   }

// If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
return View(model);
}
```

Now, change the code to force persistence. Change the line `await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);` to `await SignInAsync(user, true);`

Modified Code:

```
// POST: /Account/Login
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
        if (user != null)
        {
            await SignInAsync(user, true);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

I would then remove the checkbox on the Login.cshtml file, since you're not giving them an option.